# Choice of platform/language for user-defined hotspots

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image

When my website/web app displays a picture, I need to allow the users to define 'hotspots' on the picture wherever they click. So for example, when the user clicks on a point on the picture - 1cm² around the co-ordinate that was clicked will become a link. To be more specific - when the user clicks there to define the hotspot - a dialog will open asking for a string.

I'm pretty much open to all suggestions as to how I can achieve this but want to steer clear of flash, I know it'd be easily achieved in flash but if I can keep this all javascript/jquery it'd be a huge help.

Thanks a lot for any ideas.

For a bit more context: It will be developed using asp .net C# 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose a bit of a different approach than what Deceze said.

[Here's the working jsFiddle outlining the process](http://jsfiddle.net/nGb9t/1/)

I really went above and beyond, mostly because deceze really got me thinking.

**This is the structure of the table. For our purpose, we named the table 'coords'**

```
-------------------------
|  id  |  xpos  |  ypos |
-------------------------
|  0   |   53   |  74   |
|  1   |  217   |  168  |
-------------------------
```

**This is the click function for the 'Overlay' sitting on top of the image.** ->

```
$("#imgOver").click(function(event) {
  var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
  var defTop = event.pageY - parentOffset.top - 25;
  var defLeft = event.pageX - parentOffset.left - 25;

  $(this).append('<div class="addLink" style="top:'+defTop+'px;left:'+defLeft+'px;"> Link </div>')
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'hotspots.php',
    data: {'top' : defTop, 'left': defLeft  }
  });
});
```

In the above, we post the top and left values to our file to be parsed out and inserted into the DB. We can also create more relationships here, it's just the ti of the iceburg.

We define `hotspots.php` as the file to serve / handle our coordinate requests.

This is the function to reteive the coordinates on page load and place them into the image.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'hotspots.php',
  data: 'hotspots=true',
  success: function(data){
    $(data).appendTo('#imgOver');
    $.each($('#imgOver').find('.addLink'), function(i,obj){
      var coordData = $(this).attr('rel');
      coordData = coordData.replace(' ', '');
      coordData = coordData.split('/');
      $(obj).css({'top' : coordData[1]+'px', 'left' : coordData[0]+'px' });
    });
  }
});
```

This is the PHP code we're using to insert, and parse data retrieved from the DB.

```
if(!empty($_POST['top']) && !empty($_POST['left'])){
  $qstr = "INSERT INTO coords(xpos, ypos) VALUES('".$_POST['left']."', '".$_POST['top']."')";
  $q = mysql_query($qstr);
}
if(!empty($_GET['hotspots']) && $_GET['hotspots'] == 'true'){
  $qstr1 = "SELECT * from coords";
  $q1 = mysql_query($qstr1);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1)){
  ?>
    <div class="addLink" rel="<?php echo $row['xpos'] ?> /<?php echo $row['ypos'] ?>"> Link </div>
  <?php   
  }
}
```

Please note this is only an example, and not intended for production use. Obviously, you'll have more than 1 image and will need to develop a relationship. Also, the SQL statements I've used are vulnerable and should be secured for live use.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that works locally, but supposedly those hotspot values are supposed to be saved in the database. In which case simple absolute page offsets aren't very helpful. You'll want to save offsets relative to the image, not the page, preferably also allowing for the image to be resized.

Comment: Spot on @Ohgodwhy, another great idea. Thanks for the demo too. I'll have a good look at both options and do some reading around the two approaches you've proposed.

Comment: In response to @deceze - you can change coordinates to be used in the `offset()` by using the `element.offset().left` and `element.offset().top` to subtract from the pageX and pageY and you will end up with the same result.

Comment: As much as I really appreciate the first brilliant suggestion deceze, I'm going to accept this as the answer for the fact it includes such an ideal demo. Thanks to you both. Problem now solved.

Comment: @DeeMac I've given you the full working demo including the database calls and the php connector.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this in Javascript. Add a click handler that will intercept all clicks on the image. Figure out where in the image the user clicked; the best way is to make this relative to the image size with the top and left edge of the image being `0`, the bottom and right `1`, so a value of `0.5,0.5` means the user clicked right in the middle. You can then use those coordinates to position `<div>` elements over the image which are clickable, colored or whatever you need them to be.

All you need is enough Javascript to get the coordinates of the click event, the image dimensions and offsets and a bit of math.

Comment: Thanks Deceze, appreciate your response! What about persisting these created divs to any other visitors on other machines? As you can probably guess - I'm attempting to allow a user to add interactivity to an image that will be accessible to other users. Thanks again.

Comment: You can save those coordinates (`0.5,0.5`) into a database and recreate the `<divs>` and whatnot based on them.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot deceze. Seems spot on, easy to code/implement and very few performance considerations I'd say.